# Copy/transfer file using PowerShell 2.0

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script to copy a file from my local computer to remote computer using its IP address.

I tested my client-server connection by using this command:

```
Invoke Command -ComputerName <IP Address> -ScriptBlock {ipconfig} -Credential $credential
```

(where $credential had been entered just before this command).

I tried using the [Copy-Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849793.aspx) and [Robocopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) commands but I'm not clear if it will even take my credentials and then let me copy a file from a local to a remote machine. To be specific, would these even support **local to remote file transfer**?

A lot of times I faced errors like:
Bad username and password, source path does not exist or destination path does not exist. But I still wanted to be sure if I was on right track and using the right commands to implement what I want to or if there is something else which I should consider using. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You need to post the actual code and the error you're getting. Don't be vague. You've already tried something, and it's not working - show us what you've tried and what the failure is.

Comment: Powershell runs the commands with what ever privileges you already have.  So if you are able to copy via gui, then Copy-Item should work.

Comment: Suggests : map a network drive you can use the old `net use` command if you want. For more advance functionnalities have a look at start-bitstransfer or robocopy

Comment: @Kayasax you can also use `New-PSDrive` instead of `net use`.

Comment: Thank You everyone for providing me with such great help.
@alroc I don't have my script posted because I'm still hitting and trying commands to execute **copy-item using credentials** which would help me log into the machine and only then will I be able to push the file.
I will Get-Help regarding New-PSDrive and try implementing that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to copy a file using PowerShell remoting.  As posted in other answers, it would be simpler to use `Copy-Item` and/or Robocopy to copy from the source to a share on the destination computer.

If you want to copy the file using PowerShell remoting, you can slurp the file into a variable and use it in the remote script block.  Something like:

```
$contents = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes( $localPath )
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <IP Address> `
               -Credential $credential  `
               -ScriptBlock { [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes( 'C:\remotepath', $using:contents ) }
```

Of course, if the file you're reading is really big, this could cause the remote connection to run out of memory (by default, PowerShell limits remote connections to around 128MB).

If you're stuck using PowerShell 2, you'll need to pass the bytes as a script block parameter:

```
$contents = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes( $localPath )
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <IP Address> `
               -Credential $credential  `
               -ScriptBlock { 
                   param(
                       [byte[]]
                       $Contents
                   )
                   [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes( 'C:\remotepath', $Contents) 
               } `
               -ArgumentList @( ,$contents )
```

And yes, you must wrap `$contents` in an array when passing it as the value to the `-ArgumentList` parameter *and* it must be prefixed with the comma operator `,`, otherwise your remote script block will only receive the first byte.

Comment: Thanks !
I tried it but it gave me this error "The Using Variable cannot be retrieved........and it's valid only if ScriptBlock is invoked on a remote computer". Whereas, I did define $localPath and $contents.

Comment: It looks like you're using PowerShell 2, not PowerShell 3.  Please confirm by looking at the value of `$PSVersionTable`.

Comment: Oh yes, Thank you for making me notice this silly mistake.I missed out on that since all my remote machines are Version 3.0 I assumed this would be as well.
But does that cause a lot of differences?

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer to show what you'd have to do in PowerShell 2.  I sense an upgrade in your future. :-)

Comment: It gives me this error when I run the script mentioned above.
**Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "Empty path name is not legal."**

Comment: Make sure you set `$localPath` to the path to the file you want to copy.

Comment: Yes I exactly did that .
I set **$localPath = 'C:\folderName\fileName'** but now when I run it runs without any output or error.

Comment: Minor changes in 'C:\remotepath' and I could copy it to my remote machine. Thank you.
But i'll still be trying to send through the UNC path. It'll be good to know two ways to create my script.

Comment: @splatterd bits, I wanted to test if user is entering the correct password and only then should it copy the file. But Invoke-Command does not let me include any function after **-Credential**. Is there anyway I can make it possible ?

Answer (score 6):

One of the nice things about PowerShell is (unlike DOS) it support UNC paths. So you can literary just do:

```
Copy-Item -Path <local file path> -Destination \\<server IP>\<share>\<path>
```

Of course your account will need to have access to that location. If you need to enter alternate credentials you can pre-authenticate using `net use \\<server IP>\<share> /user:[<domain>\]<user> <password>`

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but DOS does support UNC paths, you just can't change the current directory (`cd`) to a UNC directory.

Comment: Also not relevant, but DOS was pretty much killed off a decade ago. Command Prompt != DOS.

Comment: @BACON You can! Try `pushd \\server\share`

Comment: @Kayasax When you run `pushd` on a UNC path the current directory changes to a mapped drive, not the specified UNC path.  It's basically running `net use` behind the scenes for you.

Comment: @alroc I was trying to disambiguate between PowerShell and the command prompt by mentioning DOS. A lot of people synonymize it with the command prompt (you knew what I was talking about :). Because of its ambiguous name command prompt can be confused with PowerShell. Maybe we should just refer to it as WeakShell from now on :)

Comment: @BACON I wouldn't exactly call that support :) I'll meet you in the middle -- it has partial support for UNC paths. At least it can launch programs on them.

Comment: I tried running this command from my local machine, but I face a problem.So I tested the destination path by **Test-Path -path \\<RemoteServerIP>\folder** but it returns false whereas i can see it's there.So I know the folder exists but cannot check it remotely.

Comment: @sanya If you can put that UNC path into Windows Explorer and it opens then Test-Path should also work.