# PowerShell Command to Copy File on Remote Machine

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to copy file from local machine to remote machine using PowerShell. I can copy the file to remote computer using following command:

```
copy-item -Path d:\Shared\test.txt -Destination \\server1\Shared
```

the above command uses network share path to copy the file. I don't want to use network share option as the folder will not be shared on the remote machine. I tried following commands but not working.

```
copy-item -Path d:\Shared\test.txt -Destination \\server1\c$\Shared

Invoke-Command -ComputerName \\server -ScriptBlock {
  copy-item -Path D:\Shared\test.txt -Destination C:\Shared
}
```

Please let me know how to make it working without using UNC path. I have full permissions on that folder on the remote machine.

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? Did you get an error message? No file was copied at all? File was copied into wrong location? Wrong file was copied to correct location? Something else happened?

Comment: Also when running the Invoke command the paths would be relative to the running server so then `D:\Shared\test.txt` would need to be a UNC path

Comment: I am getting error "Network Path not found".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy File Remotely with Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741609/copy-file-remotely-with-powershell)

Answer (score 8):

Quickest way I found to this, since the account being used is Administrator, is to do the following:

```
New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\MyRemoteServer\c$\My\Folder\Somewhere\
cd X:\
cp ~\Desktop\MyFile.txt .\
## Important, need to exit out of X:\ for unmouting share
cd c:\
Remove-PSDrive X
```

Works every time.

Comment: You might consider using `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location` for changing to and from X:\ directory. This would leave the current directory unmodified after the code executes, making it simpler to place within a function or similar.

Comment: This still didn't work for me. It got me halfway there though. PS 5.1. I had to use `Get-ChildItem` on the source folder and destination after it was copied. Otherwise `Copy-Item` finished too quickly and the file wasn't copied.

Answer (score 4):

You must have a shared folder to be able to copy files from one host to another, either on the remote host if you want to push the file:

```
Copy-Item -Path D:\folder\test.txt -Destination \\server1\remoteshare\
```

or on the local host if you want to pull the file:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1 -ScriptBlock {
  Copy-Item -Path \\localcomputer\localshare\test.txt -Destination C:\Shared\
}
```

Administrative shares (`\\server1\c$`) can only be used if your account has admin privileges on that particular computer.

Comment: I have the admin rights on remote machine and \\server1\c$ does not working. Getting the error "Network Path not found".

Comment: @ParveenKumar Does the Windows Firewall on server1 allow SMB connections? Can you `telnet` to port 445 on server1?

Answer (score 4):

If there is not an accessible share, you'll have to make the file content itself an argument to the script:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName \\server -ScriptBlock {
  $args[0] | Set-Content  C:\Shared\test.txt
  } -ArgumentList (Get-Content D:\Shared\test.txt -Raw)
```

Comment: Using just `-Raw` with `Get-Content` is fine for text files. For binary files, use `-Encoding Byte -ReadCount 0 -Raw`. Or use [ReadAllBytes/WriteAllBytes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17542292/145173).

Answer (score 3):

## [Powershell 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39122508/1275774) (Windows Server 2016)

Also [downloadable](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=50395) for earlier versions of Windows. `-ToSession` can also be used.

```
$b = New-PSSession B
Copy-Item -FromSession $b C:\Programs\temp\test.txt -Destination C:\Programs\temp\test.txt
```

## Earlier versions of PowerShell

Does not require anything special, these hidden shares exist on all machines.

```
Copy-Item -Path \\serverb\c$\programs\temp\test.txt -Destination \\servera\c$\programs\temp\test.txt
```

Comment: This worked for me. Did not want to use net use or connecting drives, this worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName compname -Credential $cred  -ScriptBlock { Get-Content C:\myfolder\result.txt } >>res.txt
```

Note the C:\myfolder\result.txt is on the remote computer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that worked for me for small files. Run as admin.

```
#pre 5.0 powershell copy-item to remote computer
Write-Host "Remote copy a file"
$servers = @("server01.dot.com", "server02.dot.com")
foreach($server in $servers) {
$username = 'USERNAME'
$password = 'PASSWORD'
$pw   = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $pw)
$myfile = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\Temp\srctest.txt")
$s = New-PSSession -computerName $server -credential $cred
Enter-PSSession $s
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ArgumentList $myfile -Scriptblock {[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\Temp\desttest.txt", $args)}   
Write-Host "Completed"
Remove-PSSession $s
}
```