# WriteAllBytes method throws error in Windows Power Shell version 2.0

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm new to powershell and trying to parse the value in WriteAllBytes method, after looping through the filenames with specific extension in a directory. I'm getting an error 'Exception calling "WriteAllBytes" with "2" argument(s): "Empty path name is not legal."'

The goal is to read the filename and the file contents in host machine, and create the file, with same name and contents in a remote system, under a different directory.

Below is the sample code which I am using. Valuable suggestions are much appreciated.

```
    #Powershell Version 2.0     
    $path = $Env:userprofile+"\AppData\Local\Temp\Test_Data\"

    $servers = @("server.xyz")
    foreach($server in $servers) 
    {
            $username = 'TestUser'
            $password = 'TestPassword'
            $pw   = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
            $cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $pw)

            foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.txt)
            {
                $TextFileName = $file.Name

                $FileToCreateCopyInRemote = "D:\Logs\" + $TextFileName

                $myfile = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($path+$file)
                $s = New-PSSession -computerName $server -credential $cred

                Enter-PSSession $s
                Invoke-Command -Session $s -ArgumentList $myfile -Scriptblock {[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($FileToCreateCopyInRemote, $args)} 
                Remove-PSSession $s
            }
    }
    Write-Host "Completed"
```

NOTE:
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ArgumentList $myfile -Scriptblock {[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("D:\Logs\Dest.txt", $args)}

This approach creates a single file in remote system, but I have to parse the each file name value in the place of Dest.txt

Answer (score 0):

You have to really understand about PowerShell remoting, I would suggest you to execute `Get-Help about_Remote_Troubleshooting`.

Here, I think you just need to copy file from one machine to another.
You just need to use `Copy-Item` cmdlet.

```
Copy-Item -Path c:\localPath\File.txt -Destination \\Server\c$\RemotePath\ -Force
```

If the currently running user doesn't have access, have the destination path mapped as a PSDrive in and use the same copy command, this is required as the `Copy-Item` cmdlet doesn't support Credentials.

```
$username = 'TestUser'
$password = 'TestPassword'
$pw   = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $pw)

New-PSDrive -Root \\Server\c$\RemotePath -Name T -PSPRovider FileSystem -Credential $Cred

Copy-Item -Path c:\localPath\File.txt -Destination \\Server\c$\RemotePath\ -Force
```

The remoting approach you have used here is not correct. `Enter-PSSession` can be used only for interactive remoting, it cannot be used in scripts. Scripts will always use `Invoke-Command`

Comment: Hello Prasoon, I don't have the remote destination path  mapped as a PSDrive or with Admin share.But I do have local Admin rights both in local and remote. So, I'm using Invoke command method and Write all bytes methods. Can you please suggest?

Comment: I used the above approach using the Chollid solution, which works fine for a single file.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719439/powershell-command-to-copy-file-on-remote-machine

Comment: If you have access, then you can straight away use copy-item without mapoing as drive