# why am i getting PSSession Copy-Item : Cannot find path error?

Tags: powershell

Suppose i have a dev environment and prod environment

both of these environments have a shared drive: `N:\` however the FQDN of the shared drives differ between the environments

i.e.

> dev: sharedserverdev.domain.com\data
>
> prod: sharedserverprod.domain.com\data

now suppose i have the following servers on dev and prod

> dev: server1.dev.domain.com
>
> prod: server2.prod.domain.com

the `N:`drive shows up like this on server1 and server2

[image: sharedd]

i want to retrieve a file from the prod server2 `N:` drive to the dev server1 `N:` drive.

particularly, im interested in executing this command from dev server1.dev.domain.com:

```
$backupfile = Get-ChildItem "N:\" -Filter "*Cube2*.abf" | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

Restore-ASDatabase -Server "server3.dev.domain.com" -RestoreFile $backupfile -Name Cube1 -AllowOverwrite
```

the `$backupfile` is currently retrieved from the dev `N:` drive

which works and restores successfuly on target server (in this case server3.dev.domain.com)

however, i'd like to get a backup file from the prod `N:` drive. in thsi example, `Cube2.abf` file. i clearly can see the file exists there on prod `N:\` drive

I am trying this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55572094/8397835)

```
$b = New-PSSession server2.prod.domain.com

Copy-Item -FromSession $b N:\Cube2.abf -Destination N:\Cube2.abf
```

but i am getting error

> Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'N:\Cube2.abf' because it does not exist.

ultimately, i dont even need to copy the file. i would just need to get it:

```
$backupfile = Invoke-Command -Cn "server2.prod.domain.com" { Get-ChildItem "N:\" -Filter "*Cube2*.abf" | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 }
```

but even THAT is not working either with Invoke-Command (whether running it from the prod server itself or dev server i am not getting any output except this error/warning (which from my experience is just a display line that doesnt really make a difference...). also, specifying a local drive thats not mounted, like `D:\` or `C:\` unlike `N:\` still results in that error with Invoke-Command)

```
Attempting to perform the InitializeDefaultDrives operation on the 'FileSystem' provider failed.
```

if i run this command on the prod server

```
Get-ChildItem "N:\" -Filter "*Cube2*.abf" | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

i get output:

```
    Directory: N:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        7/17/2019   3:05 PM       41033728 Cube2.abf
```

Running Net Share on prod server i get this:

```
Share name   Resource                        Remark

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C$           C:\                             Default share
D$           D:\                             Default share
P$           P:\                             Default share
IPC$                                         Remote IPC
ADMIN$       C:\windows                      Remote Admin
Folder1    D:\Folder1
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: ACL permission errors. what is displayed by the script when `net share` is run?

Comment: @lloyd net share? Where do I integrate it

Comment: you just run it as a debug command to confirm that the script has access to the folder.

Comment: @lloyd I am having some trouble,...this is a CMD command or I am supposed to run it from the same powershell script? What do I pass to it as parameters?

Comment: what have you tried, it works in both for me. remotely `invoke-command` if needed

Comment: [net share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh750728(v%3Dws.11))

Comment: @lloyd sooo like this? Invoke-Command -Cn "server2.prod.domain.com" { net share Get-ChildItem "N:\" -Filter "*Cube2*.abf" | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 }

Comment: Run the command by itself to inspect the share. It's a debugging step and has nothing to do with your script.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers but how would the command know if the script has access? Dont I ineed to pass to it params like script name and remote server? Or am I just opening a CMD in the drive on the remote server and running this command for statistical info?

Comment: The command wouldn't know. The command `net share SHARENAME` will show you the share configuration, so *you* can determine who has access.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers ok so i ran the command. i posted the output in my post :)

Comment: @lloyd i ran the command and posted the output in the post

Comment: @lloyd i still cant get files to copy. however, i was able to copy folders!

Copy-Item -Path \\sharedserverprod.domain.com\data\Cubefolder -Destination \\sharedserverdev.domain.com\data
why cant i copy files? it keeps saying it doesnt exist...

Copy-Item : Cannot find path '\\sharedserverprod.domain.com\data\Cube2.abf' because it does not exist.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i still cant get files to copy. however, i was able to copy folders!

Copy-Item -Path \\sharedserverprod.domain.com\data\Cubefolder -Destination \\sharedserverdev.domain.com\data
why cant i copy files? it keeps saying it doesnt exist...

Copy-Item : Cannot find path '\\sharedserverprod.domain.com\data\Cube2.abf' because it does not exist.

Comment: Does `net share` look like `net share SHARENAME` to you?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i get this with net share sharename: This shared resource does not exist.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2310.

Comment: Oh. My. God. Of course you need to replace "SHARENAME" with the actual name of the share you want to inspect. What were you thinking?

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers lol sorry I've been confused, but I see wat u mean now. Though, wats the point of that? I just got all share names on the server with their info in the edit I made to the post using net share

Comment: When you have access issues with a share, the first step (after checking if the share is actually mounted) is to verify both the share and filesystem permissions. The `net share` command is one way of doing the former.